# Power BI - Unable to breakdown data on Sub-category (city from country) level

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to show Revenue for each city, but the values keep getting summarised based on Country and show the same value for all the cities from that particular country.

[These are the two tables, I have country & city name in my lookup table "Location" which has a many-to-many relationship with my data table "InternetSales"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1DvX.png)

Yet, the results I'm getting is (please see below)
[I want Cities to show values relevant to them and not aggregated country fig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRdfI.png)

Comment: Are you using any measure for the summarized column? if yes, please share the measure code as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using just pick and drop columns in the report canvas and there are appropriate relation exists in between tables, you should not faced this issue. This should be just a drag and drop with a perfect output. I have attached a sample data set with power bi output for your reference (Excel part is sample data)-

[image]

After adding the data source, I simply dragged 3 columns Country, city and Revenue in the table and you can see the output is city specific.

Now, if you are using custom measure, please add measure code with your question with some sample data. That would help to diagnose the issue further.